# Concatenating two string (K&R)

Tags: c

I'm trying to mimic a sample program given in K&R, which looks like this:

```
void strcat(char s[], char t[])
{
    int i, j;
    i = j = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0') /* find end of s */
        i++;
    while ((s[i++] = t[j++]) != '\0') /* copy t */
        ;
}
```

I want to do the same thing, except that, instead of appening `t` to `s`, I'd like to copy both into a new string. My try is as follows :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void concat
(const char lstr[], const char rstr[], char outstr[])
{
    int i, j;

    i = j = 0;
    while (lstr[i] != '\0')
        outstr[i++] = lstr[i++];
    while ((outstr[i++] = rstr[j++]) != '\0')
        ;
}

int main(void)
{
    char lword[] = "foo";
    char rword[] = "bar";
    char outword[strlen(lword) + strlen(rword)];

    concat(lword, rword, outword);
    printf("%s\n", outword);
}
```

However, the above only prints garbage (I mean `f�����bar`). I can't find out where the error lies.

Comment: First things first. You should an extra bit to accommodate termination character (i.e., `\0`).

Comment: You're unnecessarily changing `i` twice (and creating Undefined Behaviour to boot) in the first loop.

Comment: @pmg: Indeed, I didn't thought to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

- No space for terminating null character in `outword`. Needs to be:

  ```
  char outword[strlen(lword) + strlen(rword) + 1];
                                           /*^^^*/
  ```
- This is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as `i` is being modified twice in the same statement:

  ```
  outstr[i++] = lstr[i++];

  /* Change to: */

  while (lstr[i] != '\0')
  {
      outstr[i] = lstr[i];
      ++i;
  }
  ```

With these two changes the program produces a new concatenated string (http://ideone.com/9QbU0q).

Comment: Thanks for the precision. I thought the allocation of space for this extra bit was automatic. Seems I need to read more of this book :)

Answer (score 3):

Every string in C needs to end with a null character, which won't be visible. It does however need to be accounted for in the size of the memory you allocate.

Answer (score -1):

When copying `lstr` to `outstr` you're incrementing your index twice. Use `outstr[i] = lstr[i++]`

Comment: And without a sequence point, making it not just too many increments but also undefined behavior.

Comment: -1 **Undefined Behaviour!** It's better to the the copying and increment in separate statements.

Comment: Oy, I didn't notice that the suggested replacement has the same problem when I +1'ed this answer and now I can't undo it. How many more things can I screw up today...